# Uncaught TypeError: styles$1.makeStyles is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, next.js, rollup

I am trying to use rollup for bundling... when running the code i am getting the following issue...
[image]

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';
const styles = makeStyles({
    subHeading:{
        fontSize:'14px',
        fontFamily: "Open Sans"
    }
});
```

The above are the part of the code

Answer (score 0):

Try to import it like this instead: `import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles/';`

Comment: I cannot use that... because I am using material-ui v5 version where there is not makeStyles... Is there any other option... Thanks for the reply...

Comment: This should help https://next.material-ui.com/guides/migration-v4/#migrate-makestyles-to-emotion

Comment: is there any way to work with makeStyles itself without moving to other in rollup?